# Recommended way to install Java with brew (just to run Java apps without a development environment)

Tags: terminal, command-line, homebrew, java, monterey

I saw today:

```
brew install --cask ripme

==> Caveats
ripme requires Java 8+. You can install the latest version with:
  brew install --cask temurin
```

There are so many `brew` packages for Java, I don't have the overview anymore:

```
brew info temurin
temurin: 18.0.1,10
https://adoptium.net/
Not installed
From: https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/blob/HEAD/Casks/temurin.rb
==> Name
Eclipse Temurin Java Development Kit
==> Description
JDK from the Eclipse Foundation (Adoptium)
==> Artifacts
OpenJDK18U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_18.0.1_10.pkg (Pkg)
==> Analytics
install: 4,556 (30 days), 14,596 (90 days), 39,378 (365 days)
```

Is this the recommend way of installing Java with `brew`?

At the moment, Java is installed with this package/tap:

```
brew info adoptopenjdk14
adoptopenjdk14: 14.0.2,12
https://adoptopenjdk.net/
/usr/local/Caskroom/adoptopenjdk14/14.0.2,12 (191.6MB)
From: https://github.com/adoptopenjdk/homebrew-openjdk/blob/HEAD/Casks/adoptopenjdk14.rb
==> Name
AdoptOpenJDK 14
==> Description
AdoptOpenJDK OpenJDK (Java) Development Kit
==> Artifacts
OpenJDK14U-jdk_x64_mac_hotspot_14.0.2_12.pkg (Pkg)
```

I don't do any Java dev work, I just use some apps which are Java-based.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `adoptopenjdk14`, the Java package you use, isn't available anymore:

```
brew info adoptopenjdk14
Error: No available formula with the name "adoptopenjdk14".
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Error: No previously deleted formula found.
```

If I search for `adoptopenjdk` instead, `brew` says that it has been superseeded with `temurin`:

```
brew info adoptopenjdk
(...)
==> Caveats
Temurin is the official successor to this software:

  brew install --cask temurin

adoptopenjdk has been officially discontinued upstream.
It may stop working correctly (or at all) in recent versions of macOS.
```

So `temurin` is definitely a good choice for a Java package.

I'd recommend that you proceed as follows: install `ripme` and see if it works with `adoptopenjdk14`, if it doesn't, install `temurin`.

Comment: I just installed Temurin, and Java-dependent apps are still complaining that there's no JRE.

Comment: @Oscar I no longer use Java, but you may have to set `JAVA_HOME`. If I remember correctly, Homebrew installs Java (or symlinks it) to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines`, so add `export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/<Java version>/Contents/Home` to `~/.zshrc` (if you use `zsh`) or to `~/.bashrc` (if you use `bash`), then open a new Terminal window for changes to take effect.

Comment: @Oscar See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49487144/how-to-set-the-java-path-installed-by-homebrew and https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/enterprise-performance-management-common/diepm/epm_set_java_home_104x6dd63633_106x6dd6441c.html for  information on setting `JAVA_HOME`. If this doesn't solve our problem, feel free to ask a question.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I got rid of Tamurin, installed Azul, and jumped through hoops to get the misbehaving application to use it. No dice; the app (the Ubiquiti network management app) is trash. I ended up installing Oracle's old, non-Apple-Silicon Java 8, which allowed the app to launch.